# Lectura de archivos para guardar datos

Tags: c++

estoy intentado hacer un programa que le pregunte al usuario un día y cuantos espacios usara este dia (100 en total para usar), al momento del usuario ingresar estos datos saldra un archivo .txt que mostrara en que dia va a estar disponible cierta cantidad de espacios.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void escribir(int dia , int espaciosR); //prototipo

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int dias;
    int espaciosT=100;
    int espacio,espaciosR;
    cout<<"digite un dia"<<endl;
    cin>>dias;
    cout<<"digite cuantos espacios usara ese dia"<<endl;
    cin>>espacio;
    espaciosR=espaciosT-espacio;
    escribir(dias,espaciosR);
    system("start registrosTest.txt");

    return 0;
}
void escribir(int dia , int espaciosR){
    ofstream archivo;

    archivo.open("registrosTest.txt",ios::app);
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"no se pudo abrir el archivo"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    archivo<<"************************************************************************************************************************"<<endl;
    archivo<<"En el dia ["<< dia <<"] van a estar disponibles ["<<espaciosR<<"] espacios"<<endl;
    archivo.close();
}
```

Por ejemplo si el usuario ingresa

```
10
2
```

le saldra un txt. que dira : En el dia [10] van a estar disponibles [98] espacios.
Mi problema consiste en que si el usuario vuelve a ingresar este mismo día,los espacios totales no deben ser 100 si no que en este caso mencionado anteriormente, sean 98 espacios totales y le reste a este numero la cantidad de espacios que usara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mi problema consiste en que si el usuario vuelve a ingresar este mismo día, los espacios totales no deben ser 100 si no que en este caso mencionado anteriormente.

El concepto que indicas se conoce como [persistencia de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistencia_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29). No puedes saber los datos de una ejecución anterior a no ser que los persistas para recuperarlos en una ejecución posterior.

Si en lugar de guardar los datos adornados (todo ese texto y asteriscos `*`) guardas sólo los datos relevantes, te será mucho más fácil leer la información de ejecuciones anteriores:

```
int leer(const std::string &archivo) // Devuelve los espacios gastados
{
    int resultado = 0;

    if (std::ifstream datos{archivo})
    {
        int dia;
        int espacio;

        datos >> dia;
        datos espacio;

        resultado += espacio;
    }
}
```

La función anterior lee días y espacio como si estuviese cada dato seguido el uno del otro, lo que significa que la escritura sería así:

```
void escribir(int dia , int espaciosR, const std::string archivo)
{
    if (std::ofstream archivo{archivo, ios::app})
    {
        archivo << dia << '\t' << espaciosR;
    }
 }
```

Tu `main` quedaría parecido a:

```
int main()
{
    int dia;
    int espaciosR = leer("datos.txt"); // Recuperamos los datos anteriores.

    std::cout << "digite un dia\n";
    cin >> dia;

    cout << "digite cuantos espacios usara ese dia\n";
    cin >> espacio;

    espaciosR -= espacio;

    escribir(dias, espaciosR, "datos.txt");

    return 0;
}
```